# file_save_upload with multiple form

Tags: files

I have a form with the following input field:

```
<input type="file" name="photo_files[]" />
```

I would like to save each of this files using file_save_upload and then change their status to permanent via `file_save`. It seems `file_save_upload` only takes a name and NOT an array. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just to make it clear that the form should be generated by Drupal or your form will not be validated. If it's a Drupal form that you have shown the HTML output, show us the form array as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do it.

```
function mymodule_testes($form, $form_state) {
// your form definition goes here
  $form = array();
  $form['upload'] = array( // note the key
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Choose a file'),
    '#weight' => -10,
  );

  $form['upload2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Choose a file'),
    '#weight' => -10,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_testes_validate($form, $form_state) {
  dpm($form_state);
  // pass proper args to file_save_upload .. see documentation 
  $file1 = file_save_upload('upload' , array()); // remember the key
  $file2 = file_save_upload('upload2' , array());
  // you dont have to do it verbosly
  // Do all your  validations  if(!$file1 || !$file2) form_set_error ...

  // save it onto form_State
  $form_state['files_storage'][0] = $file1 
  $form_state['files_storage'][1] = $file1
  dpm($file1);
  dpm($file2);

}


function mymodule_testes_submit($form, $form_state) {
 // using devel so you could see how it is stored 
 dpm($form_state);

  foreach ($form_state['files_storage'] as $key => $file) {
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through them in your submit handler:

```
foreach($form as $key => $item) {
  if($item['#type'] == 'file') {
    file_save_upload($key, array());
  }
}
```

That'll run file_save_upload on all form items with the type of 'file', you could also turn that conditional to an `in_array()` and select other file field types you could use.