# Why is my file upload widget returning an empty string?

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have built a form with the form API which contains this file upload widget:

```
$form['fid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Upload a file')
);
```

When I use it to select a file on my computer (a small .txt file) and click on `Submit`, the following validation function is executed:

```
function myForm_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  error_log("Empty string? : " . ($form_state['values']['fid'] === ""));
}
```

And it prints `Empty string? : 1` in the error log. What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting an empty string instead of a file path?

Comment: I think the file is uploaded in a core validation function so you'd probably want to move your code to a submit handler instead

Comment: @Clive I get the same result in the submit handler.

Comment: Are you trying to save a file to the file_managed table?

Comment: @Clive Eventually, I intend to use `file_save_upload` to save the file to the file_managed table, but for now, I'm just trying to get the file path to be passed to the validation (or submit) handler. Since this doesn't work, it seems premature to use `file_save_upload`, correct?

Comment: Not to skip over what you've asked but if you use a [managed_file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) type instead the uploading and saving will be handled for you. There's an example on the docs page that shows what you need to do in the submit handler to mark the file status as permanent, but other than that Drupal does all the leg work

Comment: Interesting. I'm having problems with the managed_file technique because the file upload widget is part of a tab which can be duplicated any number of times in order to upload many files and write meta data about each one and the duplication script doesn't exactly work (the duplicated file upload widget generates errors)... I will try to modify the duplication script to allow this to work, but I'm still interested in other solultions where I can receive a list of file paths in the submit handler and loop through them to upload the files (seems simpler).

Comment: [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45579/file-save-upload-with-multiple-form) might be helpful, it's pretty much the same thing and the example with the longer code extract looks like it should work

Comment: I'm still getting an empty string, but calling file_save_upload works fine. I believe it didn't work at first because I was calling it from within a class representing a database object. It only seems to work when it's called in a context where $form_state is available...